# PhpStorm (IntelliJ) environment variables on linux

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have an environment variable in my .bash_profile which is sourced in my .bashrc on my Ubuntu workstation, but PhpStorm external tools (I have a script that runs) doesn't seem to be sourcing those files. Was working on mac. Any thoughts?

Comment: Under what user are those external scripts running? Can you list the processes and check what user is running them?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I set up a new external tool in Settings > Tools > External Tools, added a new script to run and mapped it to a keyboard shortcut.